# Django. How to make a sidebar with date sorted?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm currently creating a Journal application using Django. I want to make a sidebar that includes the Year, Month and Date. Whenever the user create a new journal, it will also updated on the sidebar.

Look like this:
[image: The sidebar]

However, the result is not what I want.

[image]

I have created 10 journal entries, and it does have 10 on the sidebar, but it shows nothing.

Code:
sidebar.html

```
{% for journal in journals %}
                <li>
                    <a href="#year">{{ journal.year|date:"Y" }}</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        {% for month in journal.month|dictsort:"month" %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="#month">{{ month.0|date:"F" }}</a>
                                <ul class="submenu">
                                    {% for day in month.1|dictsort:"day" %}
                                        <li><a href="#day">{{ day.0|date:"j/n/Y" }} ({{ day.1.count }})</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="No Entry")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default="No Entry")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def journal_sidebar(request):
    journals = Journal.objects.annotate(
        year=TruncYear('date_created'),
        month=TruncMonth('date_created'),
        day=TruncDay('date_created')
    ).values('year', 'month', 'day').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by('-year', '-month', '-day')
    return render(request, 'navbar.html', {'journals': journals})
```